Adding advanced UI customizations to WSO2 API-M UIs didn't went well
I followed the steps to access the frontend folder of the WSO2  the steps in the documentation, but in the 3rd step it didn't run the mentioned command and even the next one the following step that folder src under the devportal doesn't exist or neither the other folders
is there a mistake or does anyone did it before knows about it
the project folders (under webapps)
I tried searching for other projects

If you are using WSO2 API Manager v4 or above, perform the following steps to ensure that you have the correct set of packages and dependencies in your environment.

Go to /repository/deployment/server/webapps directory and open the package.json and verify the version specified for the lerna package. It should be ^3.20.2
Try running the following command from the webapps directory itself: npm install or npm ci (if you have already installed the packages to do a clean install)

Furthermore, if you are having trouble with npm run bootstrap command, please go inside the devportal or publisher or admin path and run the npm install command to install the required dependencies.
In simple terms, Lerna is used to install all required dependencies at one-go for all the portals without navigating to them individually. Therefore, if you are having issues with running the npm run bootstrap command, follow the above-mentioned approach to install the required dependencies without any errors.
Regarding the paths mentioned in Docs, those are now updated (however the Docs were not updated) as following

devportal/src/main/webapp/source is now as devportal/source
devportal/src/main/webapp/override/src is now as devportal/override/src

Hope this helps you to resolve the confusions around. I have reported the same to the WSO2 Team with this Git

and about this instruction :
Run the command given below in the relevant application.
If it is a Developer Portal, run npm run build:dev from the devportal folder
that command  " npm run build:dev "  doesn't exist
he didn't regonize it

The npm run build:dev command should be executed from devportal folder itself. If you try running the mention command from the webapps directory it will not work. Please try the mentioned steps. Also could you please share the package.json inside the devportal folder?

yes i tired it in the devportal
PS C:\Users\MSI\Downloads\wso2am-4.3.0\repository\deployment\server\webapps\devportal> npm run build:prod
npm error Missing script: "build:prod"
npm error
npm error To see a list of scripts, run:
npm error   npm run
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-07-15T08_05_03_440Z-debug-0.log
and here's what i got

Can you share the scripts section in the package.json? All the package.json that you have shared only contains the dependencies. The scripts section contains the commands that are applicable and configured. Also, you can edit the question and attach the screenshots without posting them as an answer
